# Find all integer solutions to this congruence

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

This is what I got but I am not sure if it is correct. 
\begin{align}
& 5x \equiv 3 \pmod 3 \\
& 3 \times 5x \equiv 3\times 3 \pmod 3 \\
& x \equiv 15x \equiv 6 \pmod 3 \\
& x \equiv 0 \pmod 3
\end{align}

$x = 3k$, where $k$ belongs to integers.

Comment: The final answer is correct. Before that, not so good.  Your first step was essentially a multiplication by $0$. And $3\cdot 5\not \equiv 1\pmod{3}$.  Multiplication by $2$ would have been OK, since $(2)(5)\equiv 1\pmod{3}$.

Answer (score 2):

If your problem is $5x\equiv 3\pmod 3$, you *cannot* in any form multiplying both sides by $3$ because it would be the same as multiplying by $0$; and surely $3\cdot3\ne6$.

Since $3\equiv0\pmod3$, your problem is equivalent to $5x\equiv0\pmod3$. Add $x$ to both sides: $6x\equiv x\pmod3$. Since $6\equiv0\pmod3$ this is the same as $x\equiv0\pmod3$. So the solutions are all the numbers of the form $3k$, for $k$ an integer.

You wrote the right solution, but the path to it is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can show this is true using the definition of the congruence relation. If $a \equiv b\pmod{c}$ then $a \text{ mod } c = b \text{ mod } c$. So $5x \text{ mod } 3 = 3 \text{ mod } 3$, but $3 \text{ mod } 3 = 0$. Therefore $5x \text{ mod } 3 = 0$ which means that $5x$ is a multiple of $3$. Since $5$ and $3$ are relaively prime i.e. $\gcd(5,3)=1$, $x$ must be a multiple of $3$. Therefore $x = 3k$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.